# Does the midori js framework support chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, frameworks, cross-browser, midori

Does the midori js framework support chrome browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They don't **explicitly** support Chrome, as of the time of this answer:

> Supports all major web browsers: Internet Explorer 6+, Firefox 1.5+, Safari 2+, Opera 9+

Sicne they support Safari though, you should have very few if any issues in Chrome.